# Aligning polygons to another polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, arcgis-10.5, alignment

I am drawing the habitat map within 500 Meters boundary. Once the works area changes, I need to update all the habitats (polygon) to align with the boundary (another polygon).

Recently, I am using editing shape tool to do it.

Is there any smarter way that I can align all polygons to the boundary at once?

I am using ArcMap 10.5.1

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could tell us which software you are using, e.g. QGIS, ArcGIS, other.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What were the precise steps that you performed to get to where you are currently stuck?

Comment: @PolyGeo I want to do it more efficient. Currently, I need to go through each polygon and reshape them to align with the outer boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may need to be looking at is not necessarily editing your data but instead using a graphical clip on your data frame by a shape.

The help on [Clip to Shape](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_34075259FA074E3FB478534265098BEA) has pictures illustrating this.

Comment: Yes. It works for the area that is outside the boundary. How to fill in the gap if the area is inside the boundary?

Comment: If you don't already have that data then you need to edit it or get it some other way.

Comment: I also need to measure the area of the polygon. If after I clip the data frame, would the area of polygon changes accordingly?

Comment: If you did an actual clip it would, but the graphical clip described in this answer is graphical only so the areas inside the clipping shape would not actually change (just how much you see of them).

Comment: is that the clip in Editing toolbox?

Comment: You could do a Clip while editing or by using the Clip (Analysis) geoprocessing tool.  Both update areas of polygon features stored in geodatabases but not shapefiles.